Up from left-back
Can you explain what "up" means in this sentence?
In a recent Football game with Poland vs Netherlands

It was great work from Manchester City's Nathan Ake by the way. Up
from left-back he won the ball for the Dutch before setting up Cody
Gakpo

.

Having moved forward from his defensive position as left-back. I didn't see the game, but "move up" is what the defensive captain says (at least here in the States) when he wants the defense to shift towards midfield.

"Up" isn't only used to describe a movement upwards movement on a vertical axis.
We use "up" to describe movement in a northerly direction (eg "my uncle is coming up to visit me from the south").
We also use "up" to describe movement in any direction where the directions or borders of the area have been defined. For example, moving a gear stick on a vehicle forwards can be described as moving it "up", and that doesn't matter which way your vehicle is facing.
In your example, the playing field is a clearly defined space. Players move in a defined direction from defined positions - in this case, "left-back". So, travel away from the "back" is "up". According to Oxford Dictionary, "upfield" means "(in sport) in or to a position nearer to the opponents' end of a field".

Thanks, Astralbee. Sometimes I find the phrase "high up the pitch" in a football match report. What is the meaning of "high"/"up" in this context?Barcelona are pressing so high up the pitch.

@Nyambek it would just mean 'far' along the pitch whatever is the upwardly direction. In soccer, the teams swap sides at half time.

You use "would" in "it would ust mean...., how does "would" work in your sentence?
